# Power supply for single, standalone Eurorack module?

Tags: power

I'm totally new to anything modular. There's a particular Eurorack module I saw that I was interested in experimenting with by itself (routing audio in/out only), but there's the question of powering it outside of an actual Eurorack setup.

Are there any simple, out-of-the-box power supply options for a single module? As I understand it, modules are powered via a 10- or 16-pin connector.

Comment: This isn't a question about sound design.

Answer (score 0):

This is technically an impossible question to answer.

Power supplies for Eurorack are generally rated on the wattage and the number of connectors.

As the wattage required varies from module to module there is no specific answer to what wattage is required. However, unless there is an extremely specialist power supply out there, most power supplies put out enough power for a few modules so that shouldn't be a worry - it would be difficult to buy a power supply that was underpowered for your usage scenario.

When it comes to outputs, there are a large number of power supplies available that rely on user-supplied bus boards to distribute power to multiple modules. This would mean that you could either plug your single module directly into the power supply or build your own single output bus with both 10 and 16 pin connectors.

This difference between the 10 and 16-pin connectors is actually very simple: they both have the same 5 connections from the stripe on the ribbon cable: -12v, ground, ground, ground, +12v. The 16 pin connector adds +5v along with normalled CV and Gate connections.

In my experience (read: "buy at your own risk") 10 pin modules usually come with a ribbon cable that has a 16 pin connector for the power supply.

[image: Standard Eurorack power connections - 16pin from stripe: -12v, Ground Ground, Ground, +12v, +5v, CV, Gate. 10pin from stripe: -12v, Ground Ground, Ground, +12v.]

[image: 16 pin to 10 pin Eurorack power ribbon cable]

Conclusion: If you're looking for a power supply for a single Eurorack module, you don't need to worry about power consumption, you only need to worry about the number of outputs for the sake of neatness, and it's a fairly simple matter to build your own 16 to 10 pin adapter or to buy one for a few pounds/dollars.